# Distribution Group used for NTFS permissions?

Tags: windows, active-directory, access-control-list

I know that this is technically not possible except for mail-enabled security groups, so I'm a little confused.  We had users complain about losing access to a share.  Looking at the ACL, I saw the group where the users have been removed.  The ACE was a Distribution Group.  How is this possible?  All other ACE's listed in the ACL are administrative groups.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbTgU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, the group type was change from security to distribution.  This way if something breaks, the group type can be changed back to security while retaining the same security identifier.

You can find the attributes that have recently changed by using the command:

```
repadmin /showobjmeta dcName "[Distinguished name of group]"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm pretty new to this environment.  It appears that as part of a "deprovisioning" process, any security group going through this process is converted to a distribution group, hidden in the GAL and the members stripped from the group.  It looks like all these tasks were logged in ActiveRoles.